# Redisson - support for SCAN

Tags: redis, redisson

1. Is there a way to SCAN the keys iteratively without overloading the Redis cluster if the key size is really huge? Natively Redis supports this.
2. If the above is possible then can I control how many keys are returned in each round-trip?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer for both my questions.

1. Yes you can do this with Redisson. `Rkeys.getKeys()` does this fetching 10 keys at a time.
2. To control the count, you can use `Rkeys.getKeysByPattern(null, <count>)`. `Rkeys.getKeys()` internally uses `Rkeys.getKeysByPattern(null, 10)`